# Sharepoint 2007 Survey Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2007, survey

I am creating a SharePoint 2007 survey and noticing some odd behavior.

When I set the permissions to have users edit none of the responses, it gives users with Contribute access the ability to begin a response but after finishing the first page and clicking Next the user is no longer given access to the survey response.

However, when I allow them to edit their own responses, they can edit their response even after they submit the survey.

I'm guessing this is happening because the data is saved between survey pages and Sharepoint realizes that the user should not be able to edit any responses. Is there any way to define an end state so that a user can edit their own respones before submission (such as a drafted response) but cannot edit any responses after submission or completion? Or does Sharepoint have built in drafting somewhere in its settings?

Thanks.